# I got me a grafana.net instance, but how do I push metrics to my account?

Tags: grafana, graphite, collectd

I have setup a free account at grafana.com, but cant seem to add metrics to my dashboard:

On my server I have installed the latest CollectD(5.8.1), I have setup the `write_graphite` plugin like so:

```
<Plugin "write_graphite">
 <Carbon>
   Host "MyUserName.grafana.net"
   Port "2003"
   Prefix "collectd."
   EscapeCharacter "_"
   SeparateInstances true
   StoreRates true
   AlwaysAppendDS false
 </Carbon>
</Plugin>
```

But, when I try to setup a dashboard, I see no CollectD metrics :/

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Do you have the Graphite datasource plugin configured in Grafana? You'll see it in action here https://play.grafana.org/d/000000011/graphite-carbon-metrics?orgId=1

Comment: @Phil I have the Graphite data source enabled... Although after having just pressed the  "Save & Test" button I get "HTTP Error Method Not Allowed"...?

Comment: If you go into dev tools in your browser, open the network tab, and try the 'Save & Test' button again, you should get a more detailed error. This will tell us what is happening on your Graphite server.

Comment: Console did not show anything; but Network tab did. "405 POST Method Not Allowed"...

Comment: That's to do with your server, and not Grafana. Your endpoint doesn't allow HTTP POST methods, I'm not sure how you would enable that.

Comment: ... So how do I push metrics from my server to the grafana.net instance?

Comment: I don't think you can. You have to poll your server from Grafana.

Comment: @Phil what exactly do you mean by poll?

Comment: You data source plugin will 'poll' your Graphite DB. The datasource plugin is a module that runs in Grafana and asks Graphite for data over an HTTP connection. Do you have that installed in your Grafana instance?